# Understanding of generic forwarding during inheritance in Java

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

I have such code:

```
interface A<T extends A> {
    T method();
}

class AIml<T extends A> implements A<T> {
    @Override
    public T method() {
        return (T) this;
    }
}
```

My questin is:
Why we can't write `return this;` in method implementation.

As I underood after generic erasing this code should become like this.

```
interface A {
    A method();
}

class AIml implements A {
    @Override
    public A method() {
        return (A)this;
    }
}
```

And class casting becomes redundant.

So is it compiler not smart enough here?
Or I miss something and ClassCastException can happens here?

Comment: What if you had `class Demo implements A`, then tried `AImpl<Demo>`? `T` would be `Demo`, which would make your function `Demo method() { return this; }`. Doesn't make much sense

Comment: "interface A<T extends A>" I do not see clearly why an interface would need to take as generic argument itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare generic type `<T extends A>` it means that you want to accept *some* type which explicitly or implicitly extends/implements `A` type. Nothing more, nothing less.

You can have many types which fulfill these requirements. Lets say you have

```
class Foo implements A<Foo>{...}
```

or even

```
class Bar implement A<Foo>{...} //<-- generic type doesn't need to be Bar,
                                //    *some* other type which extends A is OK
```

Now when you are declaring `T` as

```
class AIml<T extends A> implements A<T> {...}
```

you are agreeing to same conditions as before, so it is legal to have `AIml<Foo>`. Problem is that `Foo` isn't really *related* to `AIml` so you can't return `this` as its representation.

> Or I miss something and ClassCastException can happens here?

While you are right that

```
public T method() {
    return (T) this;
}
```

will be erased to

```
public T method() {
    return (A) this;
}
```

it will allow you to only use it safely with code like

```
AIml<Foo> aimp = new AIml<Foo>();
A methodResult = aimp.method();
```

but you will get `ClassCastException` if you will want to hold result of `method()` in reference variable of same type as `T`

```
  AIml<Foo> aimp = new AIml();
  Foo methodResult = aimp.method();
//^^^-- since method() returned AIml, not Foo
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't return `this` because type `AIml<T> != T`. Casting `this` to `T` will probably end in unexpected results.